# Resources for creating a matrix of relationships between street segments

Tags: postgis, network, streets

We are looking at examining traffic in a city using data coded to [TMCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_message_channel#Development) (which are long directional links, primarily major arterials and highways, where each link is the length of multiple blocks). In order to investigate impacts of incidents and bottlenecks on adjacent streets, I thought of constructing a table like the following:

```
{street1, street2, relationship, distance}
```

where the `relationship` would be one of `[upstream, downstream, intersect, adjacent]`.

Any suggestions or resources for this endeavor? Preferably compatible with one of QGIS, PostgreSQL, Python. Does not have to be exclusive to TMCs, any form of street network.

Comment: TMC = Traffic Message Channel